# Is there integer ranges for Where Clause?

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to check that result of expression in where clause is in range of Integers.

something lke this:

```
select * from table where (col1 / col2 ) in (1..8).
```

With `(1..8)` representing a range of integers.

I mean that it must be integer, not float. So that I cant use `between 1 and 8`, because 1.2 will be correct.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can of course do this:

```
select * from table where (col1 / col2 ) in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8);
```

or

```
select * from table where (col1 / col2 ) between 1 and 8
and mod (col1 , col2 ) = 0;
```

Comment: As far as I see 2nd variant is the best option. Of course in (1,..,n) is the most intuitive, but less handy in case of wide range.

Answer (score 3):

How about

```
select * 
from table
where (col1 / col2 ) BETWEEN 1 AND 8
  and (col1 / col2 ) = FLOOR(col1 / col2 )
```

This simply checks if the fraction is in the interval, *and* integer.

Comment: The 1..8 isn't valid SQL syntax for a range.

Comment: That was copied from the question - my contribution is correct. Downvote the question instead.
I've updated the where clause to use Oracles BETWEEN function.

Answer (score 0):

You could cast it from float to int and use `between`.  (You might want to make a virutal/computed column depending on the query's performance.)

Answer (score 0):

To test col1/col2 is an integer, you could Mod them together...

Where (col1/col2) = (col1\col2) and (col1/col2) between 1 and 8

Comment: Or just as easily, test the modulo
col1%col2 = 0

Comment: \ does not seem to be an Oracle operator

Comment: @patrick you are right. Oracle wants you to use Floor(x,y) and Mod(x,y). Mine is the useless M$SQL answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pipeline function to generate integer range.

```
create or replace type my_number_collection is table of number;

create or replace function
  gen_range (p_from in number, p_to in number)
  return my_number_collection
  PIPELINED
  as
  begin
    for i in p_from..p_to loop
      pipe row(i);
    end loop;
    return;
  end;
/

select *
from my_table 
where col1/col2 in (select column_value from table(gen_range(1,8)));
```